# OpenTok: archiving and archive stream metadata

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, opentk

I've been using OpenTok (http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api) to record web chats and save them on OpenTok servers everything works fine but now I want to save additional metadata (username, firstname lastname etc.) for each stream when recording starts.

Tried to use `stream.name` and `stream.data` properties of OpenTok Stream object but nothing seem to work and assigned values are not saved with recorded stream.
May be I use something in a wrong way.

How to save/assign additional data to OpenTok stream when its created?

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently in the process of letting you do this. We know that this is something that partners want, but it is not yet implemented.

I will come back, and respond when this is available with links to the appropriate content.